# How do I save a pdf file to Google Drive?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extensions, google-docs, google-drive

If I have opened a PDF file in Chrome with its plug-in Chrome PDF viewer, how can I save it to Google Drive directly instead of downloading it first and uploading it? Is there an extension that could do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Again, I seemed to solve my own question. You could use Google Cloud Print to save any webpage to PDF in Google Drive. Check here http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/MgADSBA2jEc